# Force single argument in java varargs with Scala

Tags: scala, variadic-functions

I would like to invoke a constructor with a calculated array of parameters

```
val params=Array[Object]("abc") // Calculate the array of parameters
// java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
classOf[String].getConstructor(classOf[String]).newInstance(params)
```

It's because the method newInstance is a vararg method. How I can invoke this method with a classical array with Scala ?

Answer (score 2):

```
newInstance(params: _*)  // turn collection into argument list
```